# How to wire 3 Phase for 220V Motor

Tags: wiring

I have a used 3 Phase motor that can either run in 220V or 440V with 3 Phase power.

I looked at the wiring and there's three sets of wires, each wire has a label W6, U6, V6, etc...

There's a diagram on the inside of the wire casing but it looks like some sort of puzzle from [Jonathan Blow The Witness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Witness_(2016_video_game))

I was hoping that someone here can help me understand what this image means.

[image]

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: [How to wire three phases for 220V?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/183484/how-to-wire-three-phases-for-220v)

Comment: Could you please zoom in and crop the image. I take it that there is a neutral wire as well, so you have the option of a WYE or DELTA hookup.

Comment: Wye wired motors do not have a neutral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the lower voltage connections at the top the Wye start connections connect w6 to u6 to v6. Next w2 to u2 to v2. Those are the internal field windings to set up low voltage starting now connect u1 to u5- first phase, v1 to v5 -2nd phase and last w1 to w5 -3rd phase the little black lines are the connection points .